# Javascript toggle off re-enable css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have currently a menu which toggles on/off with a piece of javascript code, when the menu toggles on, there is css thats added to html and body to stop scrolling. Now my issue is that, when the menu toggles off the styles seem to stay so i've added some code so that overflow and height on body and html go back to auto on toggle off.

This presents two problems.

1. Menu now no longer toggles on.
2. Still the initial problem, I need the html and body to go back to its normal scrollable state.

   ```
   function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
       e.style.display = 'none';
       $('html, body').css({
           'overflow': 'auto',
           'height': 'auto'
       });
       else
       e.style.display = 'block';
       $('html, body').css({
           'overflow': 'hidden',
           'height': '100%'
       });
   }
   ```

Would much appreciate all and any help.

Thanks !

Comment: Is it showing any error in the console

Comment: Since e.style.display = 'block' and $('html, body').css({
        'overflow': 'auto',
        'height': 'auto'
    }); are not within the curly braces, css part will always be called irrespective of the condition

Comment: Put your `if` and `else` blocks in braces..

Comment: Hey @Daniel , I've put the curly braces around if and else blocks and everything is perfect now, exactly what i needed. It's a shame you didn't post that as an answer or else I would vote your answer as the correct answer. All in all, thanks a bunch you rock Daniel.

Comment: Also @MukeshAgarwal , even though you did not say to wrap if and else in curly braces, your comment still outlined where it was my mistake was. Thanks bro !

Comment: If Mukesh drops his answer, give him the honors. I don't care much about them points. I did put it down here, incase you want to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your if and else block in braces

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')

{

    e.style.display = 'none';
    $('html, body').css({
        'overflow': 'auto',
        'height': 'auto'
    });

}
    else

{
    e.style.display = 'block';
    $('html, body').css({
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'height': '100%'
    });

}

}
```